# how to add custom title to $window.open

Tags: javascript, angularjs, window.open

I am trying to implement pdf preview functionality.

This is my angular js code:

```js
 //preview document
        FileUploader.prototype.preview = function (file) {
            var ctrl = this;
            var pdfFile = file;
            var file = new Blob([(pdfFile)], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            console.log(fileURL);
            ctrl.content = ctrl.services.$sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
            var myWindow = ctrl.services.$window.open(ctrl.content);
            myWindow.document.title = "custom file name";
        }
```

I am able to preview the document but I am unable to give a custom title to the `$window.open`

[image]

I think the unique identifier is set automatically if the title is empty in the document properties.

[image]

How can I override the title?

Comment: Since the PDF preview is not a HTML page (just loading the file) the document.title option will not work. You will need to define the PDF filename to be something different that the alphanumeric string that you see now.

Comment: Also note that the behaviour for the title will differ from browser to browser when displaying files, not HTML pages.

Comment: you might want to consult Chrome documentation, this is likely a browser issue.